Getting 404 not found on preflight (OPTIONS) request on Kubernetes
I have a react frontend and springboot backend both running as a deployment on kubernetes cluster. Both have their own k8s service (clusterIP) and Ingress configured. When I try to connect from frontend Ingress to backend service (post request), the preflight request is failing with 404 not found.
I've added configs to handle CORS in backend springboot and ingress as well. I'm not sure what I'm missing here with the configs.
Frontend ingress has:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "DNT, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type, Range, Authorization, X-Project-Key"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"

I even tried adding:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;

Backend springboot CORS config class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class FaaSSvcApplicationSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of(
                "https://frontend-ingress.com" **// dummy ingress URL will be replaced by original**
        ));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

Enabled proxy in react:
"proxy": "https://faas-server-service:8080",

Post request in react:
    const response = await postRequest("https://faas-server-service:8080/v1/auth/login", user_details, headers);


Preflight is failing with 404:
Request URL:
https://faas-server-service:8080/v1/auth/login
Request Method:
OPTIONS
Status Code:
404 Not Found
But when I try to hit the backend ingress instead of the backend service, the preflight request succeeded with 200 HTTP code.
Request URL:
https://frontend-ingress.com/v1/auth/login **// dummy ingress URL will be replaced by original**
Request Method:
OPTIONS
Status Code:
200 OK

